# Program ends early in C++

Tags: c++

```
        int H;
        int M;
        int SleepH;
        int SleepM;

        cout << NumActivities[2][0];
        cin >> H >> M;

        cout << NumActivities[2][1];
        cin >> SleepH >> SleepM;

        int SubtractM;
        int SubtractH;

        if (H<=12)
        {
           int MH=24;
           int MM=60;

           SubtractH= MH-H;

           SubtractM = MM-M;
        }

           if (SleepM==00)

           {
               int SleepM= SleepM+60;

               int TimeLeftH;
               TimeLeftH= SleepH-SubtractH;

               int TimeLeftM;
               TimeLeftM= SleepM-SubtractM;

               int F;
               F=TimeLeftM/60;

               int DoThisZ;
               DoThisZ= TimeLeftH + F;

               float Normal = Normal + DoThisZ; 
               cout<<Normal;



           }

           }

        }
```

Above is my program. It's unfinished but when doing runs the program keeps ending early right after it outputs NumActivities[2][1] on line 64. I can't find any way to stop this and taking away the loop doesn't change anything.

I expect the program to let me enter the the variables H,M,SleepH and SleepM and then show me the result but it just closes after displaying NumActivities[2][1] without letting me enter the variables.

Comment: Good time to learn how to use a debugger and step through the code.

Comment: It looks like it should attempt to read two integers and then have no more observable behaviour. If any previous input has failed, those don't wait for input but fail immediately. What input are you giving it?

Comment: Why do you waste iterations #0, 1, 2, 4, 5?  If you are only checking for #3, the don't use an `for` statement, but use an `if` statement.

Comment: provide the input, the output you expect and the output you get.

Comment: I suggest running the debugger and placing a breakpoint at `if (H<=12)`.  Verify that you input two values and see what the contents of the variables are.

Comment: What makes you think it "ends early"? I can't see why it should output anything after that line. I can see why you wouldn't get your input, though: you didn't discard newlines from input (I presume you press 'enter') and you have zero error checking on `cin`.

Comment: what compiler are you using ? what platform ? try placing a getch() before the return statement in main function

Comment: @molbdnilo I give it the input "22:00:.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's supposed to let me enter the two variables but it just quits.

Comment: @ShrinjayMukherjee: It doesn't "just quit". I told you why it does what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the program asks you "What's your bedtime?(In 24 hour format):", if your answer contains colon (:), it takes input for your next question - "How long do you sleep?:" - as well.

This is because in C++, comma-separators are not part of a number, as decimal points aren't for integers, so as soon as the operation finds either the comma or the point, the extraction operation ends, leaving that character as the next to be extracted. Subsequent extraction operations find that character as the first one to be extracted, so they all return.

Enter your first answer as something like "11 30" - space between the numbers, not colon. Then, the program is supposed to take input for your next question as well.

Just to give an advice, you are wasting your iteration numbers 0,1,2,4,5. So, you can simply take away the for loop.